# 3 Table Join with addition inside of it

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
    $sql_select = "SELECT p.ideaTitle, f.feedback, f.contact
    FROM ideas p
    RIGHT JOIN feedback f ON f.ideaSlug = p.ideaSlug
    ORDER BY p.ideaDateTime, f.dateTime
     ";
```

This is what I'm working with on the new table.  I want it to display the ideaTitle, all feedback for each ideaTitle (which this gets above), and then the total number of Votes (both boolean 1 & 0) that we get in the sql code below.  I'm just having a hell of a time combining them in the correct way.  Would it be better to break this up into 2 separate sql commands?

```
    SELECT "p.ideaTitle,
          SUM(CASE WHEN v.vote = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS yesCount,
          SUM(CASE WHEN v.vote = '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS noCount
         FROM ideas p
    LEFT JOIN votes v ON v.ideaSlug = p.ideaSlug
     GROUP BY p.ideaSummary
     ORDER BY yesCount DESC
     LIMIT 20";
```

Current Code I'm using to Display the data.

```
                $result = mysql_query($sql_select,$link) or die("Insertion Failed:" . mysql_error());   
                $x=0;
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                    if ($row['ideaTitle'] != $previousTitle) {
                        ?> <h3> <?php echo stripslashes($row['ideaTitle']); ?> </h3>
                       <h4> Yes: <?php // echo $number of yes votes; ?> </h4>
                       <h4> No:  <?php // echo $number of no votes; ?></h4>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <blockquote>
                    <p><em> <?php echo stripslashes($row['feedback']); ?> </em> </p></blockquote>
                    <?php 
                    $previousTitle = $row['ideaTitle']; ?>
                <?php }
```

Comment: In the second query, why are you grouping on p.Ideasummary and not p.ideatitle?

Comment: What is the primary key of the idea table? Is it `ideaSlug`?

Comment: @Mark - yes it is     @JNK Probably an error on my part - they're always the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do this as two separate queries. You can do it in one query, but there's no real purpose in doing so.

If you *really* want to try to do it in one query it would probably look something like this:

```
SELECT p.ideaTitle, f.feedback, f.contact, p2.yesCount, p2.noCount
FROM ideas p
LEFT JOIN feedback f ON f.ideaSlug = p.ideaSlug
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        p.ideaSlug,
        SUM(CASE WHEN v.vote = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS yesCount,
        SUM(CASE WHEN v.vote = '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS noCount
    FROM ideas p
    LEFT JOIN votes v ON v.ideaSlug = p.ideaSlug
    GROUP BY p.ideaSlug
) p2
ON p.ideaSlug = p2.ideaSlug
```

However I don't see any advantage in doing this, and I see a few disadvantages.

Comment: Decided to go the 2 statement route, but I can't figure out how to connect the two - any ideas?